# Running Python script from Bash file causes Import errors

Tags: python, linux, bash

I wrote a simple bash script to run a game I am making in Python.  However, when I do this, it gives me an import error when trying to import custom modules.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/Test/game.py", line 7, in <module>
    import boot, splash, menu, game, player, options
ImportError: No module named 'boot'
```

I checked the permissions on the folder containing the modules and they are accessible. If I just run the game.py in Terminal as:

```
python3.4 game.py
```

Then everything works perfectly fine.  No import errors or anything.  Just when I run it as the Bash file.  For reference, here is the Bash file I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash
STRING="Launching game..."
PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3.4"
GAME="/home/user/Projects/Test/game.py"
echo $STRING
$PYTHON "$GAME"
```

EDIT:  It appears to be an absolute/relative path issue as to where the Bash file is and the Python file.  Running the Bash file, since the Python file is using relative path, makes it so it does not know where the source of the custom modules are.

Comment: Is the *cwd* different when you run the python3.4 interpreter vs. the bash script?

Comment: Does `which python3.4` give you `/usr/bin/python3.4`?

Comment: The directory seems to be the issue.  The import function is using a relative directory, not the full path.  When I run the python3.4 game.py I usually do it from the directory it is in.

Comment: Try adding an implicit `cd /the/correct/directory` to your script.

Comment: @indivisible  That worked perfectly!  Thanks.  I will just write that into my Bash and installer script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are concerned about *relative* vs. *absolute* paths (which do sound like they could be the potential cause here), I would recommend doing something like my code below to ensure that you use *relative* paths in the *bash* script also.

Essentially, you switch the *cwd* to the directory containing the game file, but leverage *pushd* and *popd* to ensure that the switch doesn't affect anything else. The redirection to */dev/null* is to suppress output that comes from pushd/popd which is usually just extra noise in a script situation.

```
#!/bin/bash
STRING="Launching game..."
PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3.4"
GAME_ROOT="/home/user/Projects/Test"
GAME="game.py"

pushd . > /dev/null 2>&1
cd $GAME_ROOT

echo $STRING
$PYTHON "$GAME"

popd > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, that also seems to work pretty well.  Cheers!